# Find last some records

Tags: sql, sql-server

[See this Link](http://oops-solution.blogspot.com) how to get last 10 rows using any aggregate function like for getting top 10 records we r using `top(10)`. Is sql has any predefined function for resolving this?

Comment: Do you want to know how to `select top(10) from something order by somecolumn desc`? Or..?

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson -- i want to know any function who give me last(some) records.  like top(10) give us top 10 records....

Comment: Ok, then that is what you have in my first comment get the top(10) ordered by some column descending.

Comment: ok finally sql has no command for doing this without using "order by desc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `order by` to reverse the order of the rows and then use `top(xx)`.

The is no `bottom(xx)` in t-sql.

Answer (score 1):

When using `select top` you **always** have to provide an `order by` if you want to have any control over what rows will be fetched. That means that fetching the "last 10 rows" is the same as fetching the "first 10 rows" but with a different order by clause.

```
declare @T table(ID int)
insert into @T values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

-- Get the first 2 rows
select top(2) ID
from @T
order by ID

-- Get the last 2 rows
select top(2) ID
from @T
order by ID desc
```

Result:

```
ID
-----------
1
2

(2 row(s) affected)

ID
-----------
5
4

(2 row(s) affected)
```